# How to get current session token in RSA Archer?

Tags: token, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I'm working with RSA Archer GRC 6.5 and trying to create an `iView` block with custom content. It's supposed to show results of an `ExecuteSearch` request using JavaScript. To do that I need to get a current session token, but I can't find the solution.

`CreateUserSession` and other methods, described in the documentation, are requiring login and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code that I was looking for:

```
var sessionToken = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(atob(parent.parent.ArcherApp.globals.workpointFeatures))).SessionToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexander, with 6.1 there's no way to get the session token via javascript.  It's best to upgrade to the latest version being 6.1 isn't supported any more.  This way you can obtain the session toke via javascript and take advantage of the newest features and fixes with the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it turned out that the version is 6.5, so I found the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it Alexander.